# subtracting from multiple cells in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(".minusOneBtn").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".remaining").text(function(_, currTxt) {
      return currTxt - 1;    
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Remaining Uses</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity">3</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining">15</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class=" minusOneBtn">-1</button></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Okay so lets imagine that `quantity` is like a pack that contains 30 x `remaining uses`...What I am trying to create is a simple algorithm that automatically withdraws 1 unit from `quantity`and adds 30 units to 'remaining uses' if the remaining uses of the current pack being used is 0. so simply there shouldn't be any -ve values in 'remaining uses'. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the `remaining` is less than 1, and `quantity` is greater than 1.

If so, set `remaining` to 30, and reduce `quantity` by 1.

I've set `batchSize` equal to the `data-maxNumber` attribute, but if that's not correct, simply replace it with `30`.

```js
$(".minusOneBtn").click(function() {
  //Store elements as variables to prevent repeated lookups
  var $remaining = $(this).closest('tr').find(".remaining");
  var $qty = $(this).closest('tr').find(".stockQuantity");

  //Get current values
  var batchSize = +$remaining.attr("data-maxNumber");
  var currentRemaining = +$remaining.text();
  var currentQty = +$qty.text();

  //Calculate deductions
  if (currentRemaining <= 1 && currentQty >= 1) {
    currentRemaining = batchSize;
    currentQty = currentQty-1;
  } else if (currentRemaining > 0) {
    currentRemaining = currentRemaining-1;
  }

  //Update text
  $remaining.text(currentRemaining);
  $qty.text(currentQty);
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Remaining Uses</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity">1</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining">15</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class=" minusOneBtn">-1</button></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the expected behavior? is a little confusing

```js
$(".minusOneBtn").click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
    $remain = $row.find(".remaining"),
    $qty = $row.find(".stockQuantity"),
    currRemain = +$remain.text().trim(),
    currQty = +$qty.text().trim();
    
  if (currRemain - 1) {
    currRemain--;
  } else if (currQty) {
    currQty--;
    currRemain = 30;
  } else {
    alert('NONE LEFT!!')
    return;
  }

  $remain.text(currRemain);
  $qty.text(currQty)

});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Remaining Uses</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity">3</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining">4</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class=" minusOneBtn">-1</button></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: up to you do prevent going negative if that is an issue

Comment: Apologies if the explanation wasn't clear, what I meant is, the `-1` button should withdraw `1` from `remaining uses` till it reaches `0`. Then it should withdraw a new pack from `quantity` and hence adds again the `remaining uses` by 30. as every 1 x `quantity` contains 30 x `remaining uses`. Hope that is more clear explanation. Thanks

Comment: Ok... I get it...at zero do qty -1 and add 30 to remaining

Comment: @TylerRoper no worries. Can tell your heart is in the right place

Answer (score 0):

// here is your answer

```js
function minusOneBtn(myvalue){
var uses_value = $("#uses_id_"+myvalue).val(); // get as per id remaining uses
var stock_quantity = $("#stockQuantity_"+myvalue).val(); // get stock avalable as per id

var quantity_pack = 30; // quantity pack for each 1 = 30

if(stock_quantity >= 1){ // this  data has stockQuantity greter thsn equal to one : >= 1 OR greter than zero : > 0

 var new_uses = Number(uses_value)+Number(quantity_pack);  // Number is used to 
 
 var new_stock_quantity = Number(stock_quantity)- 1; // decrease available quanity by one when it uses
 

 $("#uses_id_"+myvalue).val(new_uses); // update remaining uses on hidden input field
 
 $("#uses_display_id_"+myvalue).empty(); // empty old remaining uses on display field
 $("#uses_display_id_"+myvalue).append(new_uses); // update remaining uses on display field
 
 $("#stockQuantity_"+myvalue).val(new_stock_quantity); // update stock quantity on hidden input field
 
 $("#stockQuantity_display_id_"+myvalue).empty(); // empty old stockQuantity on display field
 $("#stockQuantity_display_id_"+myvalue).append(new_stock_quantity); // update stockQuantity on display field
 
}else{
 alert("Not allowed"); // do anything here or remove else condition
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Remaining Uses</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr>
 <input type='hidden' id="uses_id_1" value="15">
 <input type='hidden' id="stockQuantity_1" value="3">
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity" id="stockQuantity_display_id_1">3</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining" id="uses_display_id_1">15
   </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class="minusOneBtn" onclick="minusOneBtn('1')">-1</button></li>
    <!--
    minusOneBtn('1') it contains the primary or unique id that will be in your data 
    // same used in after uses_id_ => uses_id_1 and in uses_display_ => uses_display_1
    // same as for stockQuantity_ and stockQuantity_display_
    --> 
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <input type='hidden' id="uses_id_2" value="25">
  <input type='hidden' id="stockQuantity_2" value="5">
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity" id="stockQuantity_display_id_2" >5</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining" id="uses_display_id_2">25</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class="minusOneBtn" onclick="minusOneBtn('2')">-1</button></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Remaining Uses</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
    <input type='hidden' id="uses_id_1" value="15">
    <input type='hidden' id="stockQuantity_1" value="3">
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity" id="stockQuantity_display_id_1">3</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining" id="uses_display_id_1">15
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class="minusOneBtn" onclick="minusOneBtn('1')">-1</button></li>
          <!--
          minusOneBtn('1') it contains the primary or unique id that will be in your data 
          // same used in after uses_id_ => uses_id_1 and in uses_display_ => uses_display_1
          // same as for stockQuantity_ and stockQuantity_display_
          --> 
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
     <input type='hidden' id="uses_id_2" value="25">
     <input type='hidden' id="stockQuantity_2" value="5">
      <td>Suction</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity" id="stockQuantity_display_id_2" >5</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining" id="uses_display_id_2">25</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li><button class="minusOneBtn" onclick="minusOneBtn('2')">-1</button></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX submitNum"></a>
            <a href="#" class="collapseX"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
function minusOneBtn(myvalue){
var uses_value = $("#uses_id_"+myvalue).val(); // get as per id remaining uses
var stock_quantity = $("#stockQuantity_"+myvalue).val(); // get stock avalable as per id

var quantity_pack = 30; // quantity pack for each 1 = 30

if(stock_quantity >= 1){ // this  data has stockQuantity greter thsn equal to one : >= 1 OR greter than zero : > 0

    var new_uses = Number(uses_value)+Number(quantity_pack);  // Number is used to 

    var new_stock_quantity = Number(stock_quantity)- 1; // decrease available quanity by one when it uses


    $("#uses_id_"+myvalue).val(new_uses); // update remaining uses on hidden input field

    $("#uses_display_id_"+myvalue).empty(); // empty old remaining uses on display field
    $("#uses_display_id_"+myvalue).append(new_uses); // update remaining uses on display field

    $("#stockQuantity_"+myvalue).val(new_stock_quantity); // update stock quantity on hidden input field

    $("#stockQuantity_display_id_"+myvalue).empty(); // empty old stockQuantity on display field
    $("#stockQuantity_display_id_"+myvalue).append(new_stock_quantity); // update stockQuantity on display field

}else{
    alert("Not allowed"); // do anything here or remove else condition
}

}
</script>
```